# Can't Boot Computer From Any Way Possible

Tags: windows, boot, usb, bios

I have a HP laptop was trying to upgrade to windows 10 last week, looks like something went wrong during installation and since then i can't boot my laptop anymore, 
**Things I've tried**

1. booting via usb (with a windows created bootable usb) gives me an error "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or      Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key" (I've tried Legacy and UEFI)
2. booting from dvd via usb (the laptop doesn't have a cd/dvd slot so everything goes thru usb) takes me to the installation screen but then it gives me this error "A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing.  If you have a driver floppy disk, CD, DVD, or USB flash drive, please insert it now.  Note: If the Windows installation media is in the CD/DVD drive, you can safely remove it for this step"
3. Doing The same and selecting repair computer gives me this error "This    version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with the version of windows you are trying to repair. Try using a recovery disc that is compatible with this version of windows."
4. System Recovery Gives me This Error "your pc/device needs to be repaired Error code 0xc0000225"
5. scanning the memory and hd didn't bring any results

So my question is is there anything else i can try on it? or it's easier to use it as spare parts for my next computer??

Comment: Message #2 sounds familiar. I had the same problem when trying to install windows 10 from an USB2 pendrive on a skylake board. The solution which worked for me was to buy an USB3 pendrive and install/rescue from that. (All pendrives I had before that were either USB2 or eSATA).

Comment: Try finding a download for Win 10 recovery disk? And you can use a software to "virtual mount" the download so you can read it like a virtual disk drive.

Comment: @Hennes thanx but tried both didn't work on either of them

Comment: @lasrtb Since it's a clean install i'd try creating another bootable usb from another pc, i've had issues before where the bootable usb has messed up installs or if you can get to the installation screen you can use shift + f10 to enter a command prompt and run a chkdisk to see if there's any issues with the hard drive.

Comment: @ejbytes what do you mean by 'virtual mount'? my laptop is dead i can only boot from usb or so windows isn't booting at all and booting via disk was my second try which failed

Comment: @RyanIG the last thing i did was checking the memory but found nothing, and the usb i've tried a few usbs that i've used before on other computers with no problem, also tried on new one that i made with the media creation tool but none of them worked

Comment: @lasrtb  Ok, please be more verbose then. What OS version you have the disk for? your computer model number? your DVD drive model number? Which file did you download and what procedure did you use to create a bootable  usb-flash-drive (because it looks like the bootloader was not written correctly)

Comment: @JackWhite ok well i wrote that i've tried legacy and UEFI meaning that i tried windows 7 and windows 10 both were legit windows downloads that i've used on other computers with no issues, tried creating it with windows creation tool and via rufus both with the same results, my laptop is a hp spectre x360 and i'm using a lg usb dvd drive (no idea the model have it for the longest time already)

Comment: Oh, ok, HP with all USB3.0's, I probably should have guessed it. UEFI does not imply Windows 7 or 10 and you didn't list if it's 32-bit or 64-bit. It appears that `Rufus` didn't write the bootloader properly for some reason but that doesn't matter since you would get the same error anyway. I posted another answer - please try it and report the results if any (I will probably delete the original answer)

Comment: Regarding #2 and #3 in your question. A "virtual mount". On a different computer, a friends computer or your relatives computer, search "How to Create a Virtual DVD or CD on a USB Drive". You will be able to use a virtual CD/DVD on your usb to boot the drivers. You can create a driver disk (virtual disk on a usb); you can create a virtual repair disk (on a usb).

Answer (score 0):

Don't panic. Your computer should be ok.

### Rescue your files

First of all, you said you were *upgrading* to windows 10. If you didn't backup your personal files (like text documents) before upgrading, be careful since installing Windows from disk *may* erase them (if you choose to format or repartition the disk)

If you didn't erase the disk yet, your files should still be on the disk. Files on `Desktop` and in `Documents` folder are normally stored in `c:\users\(your_user_name)\`. Try [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/135005/how-to-use-a-windows-installer-disc-to-back-up-your-files-when-your-computer-wont-boot/) guide if you need them. You may run into exact same problem you already described however - see below.

### Fix the "missing driver" problem

In your scenario options 1,3,4,5 will not work because you were in the middle of upgrade process and it failed. You need to reinstall the system to make it usable again.

The real problem is the error: `A required CD/DVD drive device driver is missing.`

What it windows DVD trying to say is that it cannot find a driver file that would allow your DVD-drive to function.

There may be different reasons why this could happens:

- Windows cannot find a driver for your USB-DVD drive. I don't think this is a likely case since you somehow booted from it.
- Windows cannot find a driver for your USB-port. If it is a USB 3.0 port (blue color), try connecting the drive to USB 2.0 port (colored black or white).
- If the DVD disk you are trying to boot is not an official windows installation disk, or is for another computer model, or you downloaded it somewhere and burned it, it may not be compatible with your computer. Try a different disk.
- The drive just cannot read the required file off the disk. Your disk may be dirty. Try gently wiping disk surface with a clean cloth that does not leave any threads behind, such as one for cleaning monitor screens or glasses. Do not use cleaning liquids as they may damage the disk and the drive.
- You drive may be faulty. This happens even if it always worked and you last used it ages ago. Try different drive if you can.
- If nothing helps, see next section

### Create a bootable USB

I suggest you abandon the DVD and write Windows setup onto a USB-stick flash drive.

You will need a working computer with internet connection.

- Find a USB-drive (at least 8GB should be enough)
- Copy any files off your USB-drive. Following steps will erase all files from it
- Download Windows installation file from [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/)

  - If you don't already have a Windows 10 license key, you will have to download whatever version you have a valid license number for (select from the top of the download page). Upgrading from Windows 7 and 8 to 10 is no longer free now.
  - "Windows 10 N" is for Europe and "KN" is North Korea
  - Please remember which version (32 or 64 bit) was installed and licensed on you computer. If yours has a license label on the bottom, refer to it.
- Navigate to [this page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/). Download the tool and refer to usage guide on that page.

  - You will need to do a `clean installation`, not `upgrade` because the latter may fail if the system in question is not working properly before upgrade as is in your case.
- Insert USB-stick in your computer and turn it on. If it will not boot from USB, read you computer manual on how to get into a boot menu. Usually you need to press F8 or F12 upon boot several times.
- Install Windows normally. It should work.
- If you still get a same or similar error, update your quiestion with exact model number of your computer (see stickers on the bottom) and windows version you are trying to install.

Comment: regarding first answer yes it's a clean new official windows installation disk and tried it on all ports, regarding second answer check the first thing i tried, i know the entire process of installing windows and troubleshooting but none of those worked as mentioned in question  (note: i've edited the question for a bit better understanding), thanx anyway

Answer (score 0):

All of your laptop's ports are USB3.0 (they imitate USB2.0 ports but only when booting; not colored blue for no sane reason)

Also I see no reason not to include a $1 Windows installation DVD with $1000 laptop, but then that's HP for you.

Anyway, looks like your laptop actually does need drivers to install the OS, and HP website does not provide them directly. Here is what you need to do:

- Navigate to [HP software download website](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/portal/site/hpsc/public)
- Select `More product selection options` -> `Enter product serial number`

  - Look for serial on the bottom of your computer and enter it
  - Navigate to download page for your hardware revision
  - If the search doesn't work (I wouldn't be surprised) try [x360 G1](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=7739481&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4063) or [x360 G2](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=8737500)
- Select the Windows version your are installing and English language

  - expand `Driver - Controller` category
  - select a `USB 3.0 controller` driver (for me it was: `Intel USB 3.0 Host Controller Driver (American, International)`)
  - Download the driver
- Run (just double-click) the driver installer on any windows PC

  - It should ask to accept an EULA and select installation folder
  - It may complain about incompatible OS or wrong driver or something like that - that is ok
- Locate the folder you installed the driver to (default: `c:\swsetup\(packagename)\`).

  - Copy contents of this folder to any USB-flash-drive.
- Now boot windows on your laptop as you did before

  - Verify the installation DVD has the same version that you have downloaded the driver for, that is: **64-bit** version on Windows 7, 8.1 or 10.
  - When asked for driver, insert the usb-flash-drive, click `Browse` and select the folder you downloaded the driver to.
  - If it doesn't work, try finding the subfolder with relevant driver files (`*.inf`). For me it would be folder `e:\swsetup\SP70655\Drivers\Win7\x64\`.
  - Don't worry if there is no `Win10` folder for example - in that case `Win7` or `Win8` will do. Try different folders
  - Click `Ok` to continue with installation. Windows should normally load the drivers and continue as normal
  - If this doesn't help please comment